# save button is not being displayed at the end of layout in android

Tags: android, android-layout

[http://imgur.com/EqJXUbb]
Hi In this code I am displaying two edittext's and one checkbox and button named as save.Now Save button I want to display the end of the layout.now save button is displaying end.suppose In my table layout having 10 table rows means it displaying middle 
**xml**

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" 
    android:background="@drawable/attendance">

    <LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" 
    android:gravity="top" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
         >
          <Button
         android:id="@+id/back"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
         android:background="@drawable/back"
         />



         <Button
             android:id="@+id/home"
             android:layout_width="wrap_content"
             android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:background="@drawable/home"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true" 
             android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
             />

      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            />




     </RelativeLayout> 
<RelativeLayout 

    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
      <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tv1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:layout_gravity="left"
            android:textColor="#FF0000"
            android:textStyle="bold"

            /> 
    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:stretchColumns="1,0,0" >



        </TableLayout>

    </ScrollView>


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="save" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/studentname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:ems="10" 
        android:visibility="invisible"
        >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rollnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/save"
        android:ems="10" 
         android:visibility="invisible"/>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/present"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1"
         android:visibility="invisible"
         />
    </RelativeLayout> 
</LinearLayout>  

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: post a snap-shot of screen here... so we can understand better..

Comment: how to post the snap shot

Comment: Google it... that will help you more thn I could..

Comment: Give the weight to scrollview of 0.97 could resolve your issue else you have to show screenshot that what you wanna create ?

Comment: I have less reputation it's showing u cannot uplaod image

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you designing in this case first set layout align top and another(the layaout to be at bottom) is align bottom and place all other layouts are between these two layouts..

```
RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#ffffff" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:background="#FF0000" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/back"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:background="#ffffff" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/home"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
        android:background="#c1c1c1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:textStyle="bold" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/below"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/save"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:text="save" />
</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/below"
    android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#FF0000"
        android:textStyle="bold" />

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        android:scrollbars="none" >

        <TableLayout
            android:id="@+id/maintable"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:stretchColumns="1,0,0" >
        </TableLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/studentname"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/rollnumber"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:background="#c1c1c1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:visibility="visible" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/rollnumber"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/tv1"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="#c1c1c1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/present"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:visibility="visible" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: how to set tv1 to top of the page